# Jquery consumindo Web Service Rest

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

Gostaria de listar os ceps desse json, segue ele:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Hospital Da Mulher",
    "cep": "60508090"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Hospital Maria jose",
    "cep": "2"
  }
]
```

E esse é onde eu to chamando:

```
 $.getJSON('/MinhaDoenca/rest/hospital/get',
                    function(data) {

                        alert("O cep é:  " + data.cep);

                    });
```

Gostaria que listassem todos os ceps do meu json, como devo prosseguir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve percorrer os itens do array pegando cada cep dos objetos. Segue:

```
for( var index in data ) {

  alert( data[ index ].cep );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução feita com `jquery` usando o `$.each` para percorrer o objeto.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var dados = [{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": "Hospital Da Mulher",
  "cep": "60508090"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "nome": "Hospital Maria jose",
  "cep": "2"
}];

$.each(dados, function(key, val) {
  alert('id=' + val.id + ' nome=' + val.nome + ' cep=' + val.cep);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```